# How to install launch.py files in a python package in ros2 (python package is created without CMakeLists.txt)?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! The question as in the topic.

When I just create a python package as described in this ros tutorial [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package.html), and then manually create a `launch/launch_file.py` and do `colcon build`, I cannot execute `ros2 launch my_package launch_file.py` becuase `file '.launch_file.py' was not found in the share directory of package 'my+package' which is at 'path/2/ros_ws/install/my_package/share/lidar_odom'`.

I do not have `CMakeLists.txt` in my package because this file is not created when you create a python package following the mentioned ros tutorial.

How to install then my launch files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388320/how-to-install-launch.py-files-in-a-python-package-in-ros2-(python-package-is-created-without-cmakelists.txt)?/) by [mac137](https://answers.ros.org/users/69218/mac137/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@EtienneSchmitz, many thanks for your answer! Maybe this particular code did not work in my case, but it inspired me to modify it a bit and the following piece of code worked for me

```
setup(
...
data_files=[
...
('share/' + package_name, ['launch/launch_file.py']),
],
...
)
```

---

Originally posted by [mac137](https://answers.ros.org/users/69218/mac137/) with karma: 83 on 2021-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

You don't add your launch files in data_files (`setup.py` in your python package folder).

```
setup(
...
    data_files=[
    ...
    (os.path.join('share', package_name), glob('launch/*.launch.py'))
    ],
    ....
    )
```

You will find more explanation on this [link](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-launch-file-example/)

---

Originally posted by [EtienneSchmitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/77536/etienneschmitz/) with karma: 11 on 2021-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1